# Process image with Imagemagick to "default palette" (for example 16 or 256 colours)

Tags: colors, imagemagick

Currently I'm processing image to extract main colors from it with such:

```
-resize '50x50' -colors '8' -colorspace 'RGB' -quantize 'RGB' '/tmp/downsampled20190502-27373-iqgqom.png'
```

However, it returns me a lot of colours, so I have to limit them to the main palette (like white/black/red/etc), so I guess 8 or 16 colours would be enough for me.

I thought that `-colors '8'` should process it, however, it only returns primary 8 colours from the image.

Do you have any ideas about how I could extract colours and convert them to 3-bit (8-color palette)

*I though convert it to GIF, however GIF contains 256 colour palette.*

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. What version of ImageMagick are you running - try `identify -version`. Also, this generates potentially 1,000,000 different colours but I only get 8 as a result - can you try please? `convert -size 1000x1000 xc:red +noise random -colors 8 result.png` Count the colours with `identify -format %k result.png`

Comment: Do you mean you have, or want to create, a personal palette and apply that to lots of images?

Comment: You can make a list of colors that you want to use. Then make that into a color map image. Then use -remap to force the image to have only those colors by reassigning your pixels to the closest color. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap

Comment: for example logo of Google — I want to have an extraction of colours like:
(blue
red
yellow
green)
not semi-colours

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to map all colours to one of 8 *"primaries"*. So, let's make a palette of acceptable colours:

```
convert xc:red xc:lime xc:blue xc:cyan xc:magenta xc:yellow xc:white xc:black +append palette.gif
```

And enlarge it and look at it (because at the moment it is only 8x1 pixels):

[image]

Now take this `colorwheel`:

[image]

and remap all the colours to your *"acceptable"* palette **without** dithering:

```
convert colorwheel.png +dither -remap palette.gif result.png
```

[image]

and now remap **with** dithering:

```
convert colorwheel.png -remap palette.gif result.png
```

[image]

---

You can make your own palette - you don't have to use my colours, and you can make any RGB/HSL, hex colour you like, e.g.:

```
convert xc:"rgb(10,20,200)" xc:"#ff7832" xc:"hsl(10,40,90)" +append palette.gif
```

---

If you want the names and hex values of the colours in the resulting images:

```
convert result.png -unique-colors txt:
```

**Sample Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 7,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
1,0: (0,65535,0)  #00FF00  lime
2,0: (65535,65535,0)  #FFFF00  yellow
3,0: (0,0,65535)  #0000FF  blue
4,0: (65535,0,65535)  #FF00FF  magenta
5,0: (0,65535,65535)  #00FFFF  cyan
6,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
```

Comment: perfect start! and how I could extract existed colours only from the image after that?
I mean that `colorwheel` doesn't have black and white, so I need a list of all colours except them

Comment: I have updated the answer top show how to list colour names and hex values - note that ImageMagick uses the SVG colorname `lime` where you might expect `green`.

Comment: do you know a way how I could convert it for example for 256 colors? do I need create a palette by hand? or there is some build in solution?

Comment: It depends what you want to do, but you haven't answered my questions in the comments area. Do you want to always convert your images to a fixed set of N colours that is always the same N colours, or not? If not, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: yes, I want to always convert to a specific number of colours 
`convert colorwheel.png -type palette -depth 1 -colors 8  -unique-colors txt:` looks like it's what I need, thank you!