# Loading & Saving Bitmap Images In OpenCV (OpenCV Version = 3.1.0)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

My problem is simple at least as I see, or how I feel about it.

I tried to load and write **Bitmap** images with **OpenCV** in **C++** and got sucessed in it, my problem is about the way the image is loaded and written.

Here is the thing: I working on **256-color palette (8bpp)**, trying to edit or add somethings on it, and then I write it or you can say I save it.
The problem is that the **color palette** before and after loading the image is **not the same**.
It seems like OpenCV is not just load the image but also change the palette color, in my case it is changed to **RGB color (24bpp)** which cause of an output image with **size 3** x **original image size** after I saved the loaded image.

My question **is there a way to load it or write without changing image color palette?** if not possible, **is there a way to write it with specific color palette?** so I can specify it to **256-color palette (8bpp)**, if not possible either any possible **converter** will be good (from **RGB color (24bpp)** to **256-color palette (8bpp))**.

Here is my **code** to load and write the Bitmap image:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat BitImage = imread("BitImage_Intput.bmp", -1); // -1 To load image as it is (without changing) but not working.
    imwrite("BitImage_Output.bmp", BitImage); // To write or save the image.
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I found this function, `imread("BitImage_Intput.bmp", CV_8UC1);`, It does the job in a side but ruins it on the other side, the color palette not changed but I got a **GRAYSCALE** image (All colors except **white** and **black** are removed or replaced).

> [**The 256-color palette (8bpp) Bitmap Image**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EV4rvsM7iV5Pl8b0CFc0UkkYvpzbpv_U/view)
>
> [**The RGB color (24bpp) Bitmap Image**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQyeWyp_XcZc36pAI1g69Tjrvz2o8FDf/view)
>
> [**The GRAYSCALE (8bpp) Bitmap Image**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y9nGbOYO34EU77f21vKLFXt5iGNF3NVg/view)

Comment: AFAIK, OpenCV doesn't deal in palette images very much at all, it just makes them RGB. You don't actually say *"why"* you want to stick to a known palette, but one solution might be do your work in OpenCV, save and then map to specific palette with **ImageMagick** https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965617/2836621

Comment: Of course, you could write your own BMP reader and writer and be sure to use only NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR resampling and disable anti-aliasing for drawing and text to avoid introducing new colours...

Comment: @ Mark Setchell: Ah, I tried **ImageMagick**, it needs to be installed on the operating system, waht I need is a standalone executable so i find OpenCV with C++ as best solution, I found solution in Python as well but the executable size is too much big (about 30 MB), Thank you anyway for making things more clearer, it is really strange how can OpenCV miss this thing.

Comment: @ Mark Setchell:, How so? I don't understand much in that.

Comment: It's because OpenCV is for *"Computer Vision"*... cameras don't produce palette images or images with transparency so OpenCV doesn't focus on that.

Comment: Alright I see, so no better option than **ImageMagick** as I see you telling me, I will try to deal with it with this one. Thanks Mark Setchell that is helpful.

Comment: @ Mark Setchell: Man I love you so much, **ImageMagick** is just awesome, it fixs my problem, wow man how I miss this thing I searched a lot in OpenCV forums and ImageMagick was there saying just come and try me I feel sometimes like I'm blind...Thanks so much again.