# Convert jpg to png with predefined color codes?

Tags: colors, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've got some maps, based on 66 colors, that I unfortunately saved in jpg for a couple of months ago.

I've discovered that I can convert to png, and set it to be 66 colors, BUT, is there anyway to predefine those 66 colors, so for example the colors close to #888888 will be converted to #888888 and not to 878787 and 878887.

One issue is also that the maps don't contain all 66 colors,(usually around 30) so now I might get 4 different type of white. (that's why I need this solution)

is this even possible with imagemagick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a 66x1 pixel *"swatch"* of the 66 colours you want by taking one of your original PNG images and extracting the unique colours like this:

```
magick original.png -unique-colors swatch.png
```

Then you can apply it like this:

```
magick unhappy.jpg -remap swatch.png result.png
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965617/2836621).

---

Here's a concrete example. Here's our map:

[image]

First, make a swatch of the 5 colours we want to appear in our output image:

```
magick xc:"rgb(10,100,140)" xc:"rgb(240,190,120)" xc:"rgb(70,130,30)" xc:"rgb(220,230,230)" xc:"rgb(40,80,50)" +append swatch.png
```

[image]

Now remap all the colours in the original to the 5 colours in the swatch:

```
magick map.jpg +dither -remap swatch.png result.png
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, we could let **ImageMagick** choose the best colours for the swatch like this:

```
magick map.jpg -colors 7 -unique-colors swatch.png
```

[image]

And remap just the same as before but using the colours **ImageMagick** chose:

```
magick map.jpg +dither -remap swatch.png result.png
```

[image]

---

Note that you can use hex codes ([or HSL, or Lab colours](https://imagemagick.org/script/color.php)) just the same:

```
convert xc:"#0a658c" xc:"#f0be78" xc:"#46821e" xc:"#dce6e6" xc:"#285032" +append swatch.png
```

Note that the above commands assume **ImageMagick** v7. If you are obliged to use old v6 syntax, replace `magick` with `convert`.