# Posterize to 1 bits per channel + extra luma bit

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagick's `-posterize 2` flag can be used to convert an image to 1 bits (2 levels) per R/G/B channel. But is there a way to convert to a format where I have two sets of 8 colors, with half and with full intensity? In other words, [my target format is 4 bits per pixel: 1 bits per R/G/B and 1 fourth bit for luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_color_formats#4-bit_RGBI).

EDIT for clarity based on some comments:

With `-posterize 2`, you get 8 colors total, since you have three channels and two levels per channel (since 2³ = 8):

- [`0 0 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/000000)
- [`0 0 1`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/0000FF)
- [`0 1 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/00FF00)
- [`0 1 1`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/00FFFF)
- [`1 0 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/FF0000)
- [`1 0 1`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/FF00FF)
- [`1 1 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/FFFF00)
- [`1 1 1`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/FFFFFF)

Now imagine I have access to seven more colors (because "half-bright black" is still just black):

- [`0 0 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/000000)
- [`0 0 0.5`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/000080)
- [`0 0.5 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/008000)
- [`0 0.5 0.5`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/008080)
- [`0.5 0 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/800000)
- [`0.5 0 0.5`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/800080)
- [`0.5 0.5 0`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/808000)
- [`0.5 0.5 0.5`](https://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/808080)

So I'd like to quantize (?) my picture to these total of 15 colors.

As for the output format, it shouldn't matter, the same way you can use `-posterize 2` to e.g. produce a PNG that is formally 24-bit RGB, it just doesn't contain any non-0 or 255 values in any channel.

Comment: Please clarify this "two sets of 8 colors, with half and with full intensity". You have only 3 channels. If each has 50% and 100% intensities, that is only 6 colors.  What are the other 2 colors?

Comment: So effectively you want 3 bits to tell you which one of the 8 colours it is and 1 bit to tell you if it is from the 100% or the 50% intensity set of colours, correct? Who/what is going to read/understand this format? What file format? PNG?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just need access to the resulting pixel color choices, the format is irrelevant -- I'm going to use that on an 8-bit microcomputer anyway, this is just an intermediate tool in a toolchain.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want **ImageMagick** to determine the output colours itself, instead you want it to map all the original colours to the nearest of a set of 8 output colours you specify *"up front"* yourself?

Comment: If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64907846/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965617/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Mark Setchell's comment, using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64907846/477476) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965617/477476) answers I was able to do this with a two-step process:

1. Generate an image containing the palette

   ```
   $ convert  $(for l in 128 255
     do
       for r in 0 $l
       do
         for g in 0 $l
         do
           for b in 0 $l
           do
             echo "xc:rgb($r,$g,$b)"
           done
         done
       done
     done) +append palette.png
   ```

   This generates a file with 16 colors, because `xc:rgb(0,0,0)` is generated twice; but that should be OK AFAICT.
2. Use this palette for color mapping

   ```
   $ convert foo.png +dither -map palette.png result.png
   ```

While this does technically do what I set out to do, it turns out its result is quite poor; but [that's for a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77474361/477476).

Comment: You can add `-unique-colors` as the penultimate parameter to remove the duplicated value.